# How to stop AS3 timer class-based animation in another frame?

Tags: actionscript-3, timer

I have a project which consists of 4 frames (+ one starting frame), where each frame contains a Timer class based-animation.

You can visit each frame by selecting the appropriate button.

Let's say the animation in frame1 lasts for a total of 30 seconds, but I'm too impatient to watch it and decide to go frame2, which also I don't like. In the background however, the animation for frame1 is still running, for when I go to frame 2 and go back to frame1, the animation starts both from the beginning and also continues to play from where I left off.

I also get an error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Kan geen eigenschap of methode benaderen via een verwijzing naar een object dat null is.
at fl.transitions::TransitionManager/saveContentAppearance()
at fl.transitions::TransitionManager/set content()
at fl.transitions::TransitionManager()
at MethodInfo-111()
at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

Is there any solution for my problem?

How can I stop an animation when I'm leaving one frame so when I'm visiting it again it starts from the beginning instead of halfway?

Thank you for reading!

Here's my code:

Array buttons

```
var knopArray:Array = new Array(knop1, knop2, knop3, knop4);
```

Array functions

```
var functionArray:Array = new Array(naarFrame1, naarFrame2, naarFrame3, naarFrame4);
```

Hooking up eventlisteners

```
for(var i:int = new int (0) ; i < knopArray.length; i++){
        knopArray[i].buttonMode = true;
        knopArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, klik)   
        function klik(event:MouseEvent):void{
            for(var i:int = new int (0) ; i < knopArray.length; i++)
                if (event.currentTarget == knopArray[i]){
                    knopArray[i].addFrameScript(0, functionArray[i]);
                    }
                }
        }
```

go to frame and start tweens

```
function naarFrame1(){
        gotoAndStop("frame1");
        var timerEenA:Timer = new Timer(1000,1);
            //animations
        timerEenA.start();
        }

function naarFrame2(){
        gotoAndStop("frame2");
        var timerTweeA:Timer = new Timer(1000,1);
            //animations
        timerTweeA.start();
        }
```

Comment: where are you handling the `Timer` events? I think that's what's causing your NULL error

Comment: My AS3 code is in the first frame, the other frames (and their animations) are in the consecutive frames. Is that what you mean? I'm still learning AS3.

Comment: As far for the code you posted I just see you starting two `Timers`, I don't see where you're acting on their completion or ticking. So I'm wondering where you placed the `timerTweeA.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TimerEvent.TIMER);`

Comment: The addEventListeners are actually where the //animations comments are, for the sake of clarity I omitted them from the code, for I don't think the problem is in there. Thank you for commenting!

Answer (score 0):

On your first frame, called "init" (or something like that), which will have no animation:

```
var buttons:Array = [ button1, button2, button3, button4 ];
var frames:Array = [ "frame1", "frame2", "frame3", "frame4" ];

for each (var button:MovieClip in buttons)
{
    button.buttonMode = true;
    button.mouseEnabled = true;
    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickListener);
}

function clickListener(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
    {
        if (event.target == buttons[i])
            gotoAndStop(frames[i]);
    }
}
```

On your second frame, called "frame1":

```
// This will give you a 20 second animation, with 1 second updates.
var timer1:Timer = new Timer(1000, 20);
timer1.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timer1Listener);
timer1.start();

function timer1Listener(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    // do something
}
```

On your third frame, called "frame2":

```
// This will also give you a 20 second animation, with 100ms updates.
var timer2:Timer = new Timer(100, 200);
timer2.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timer2Listener);
timer2.start();

function timer2Listener(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    // do something
}
```

Etc...This can be done more cleanly using objects, but this should achieve the effect you want.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm not able to try it out right now, but as soon as I have time I will :-)